# Joomla .htaccess mod_rewrite to a menu not an article

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

I already have a functional .htaccess rewrite that rewrites a custom URL and shows the content of a certain menu.

But it doesn't show it has a menu item, it shows as an article!

- If I navigate to http://www.mysite.com/en/mymenu/thesubmenu I can see
  the content in the menu context (title has link, date not shown, etc)
- If I try to go to the rewriten URL http://www.mysite.com/custom, it
  shows the content like an article (ex: the title doesn't have a link,
  shows date, etc).

**I would like to rewrite it in a way that the content is shown as a menu (as intended), how do I do it?**

I suppose there is some conflict in the redirects, or the menu is redirected before my custom .htaccess?

I tried every combination I could think of.

My current .htaccess (relevant part):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2308&Itemid=545&lang=en [L]
```

---

What I've tried and gives not found:

(By the way, if I put http://www.mysite.com/?option=com_content&Itemid=545 in the browser address bar, it shows the menu as intended)

```
RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ /en/?option=com_content&Itemid=545 [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ /?option=com_content&Itemid=545 [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ ?option=com_content&Itemid=545 [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ /en/index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=545 [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ /index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=545 [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=545 [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ /en/mymenu/thesubmenu [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ /mymenu/thesubmenu [L]

RewriteRule ^(en/)?(custom)/?$ mymenu/thesubmenu [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up to be a conflict in the SEO redirects that Joomla makes.

The solution is to use an internal rewrite done via a plugin (I custom made it), this way the rewrite will show the correct content in the correct context (as a menu item in this particular case).

As I can see it, because of the conflict, this is the only solution and in the end doesn't/must not be done via the .htaccess.